# Use condition to get inside associative array

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I have following data coming in data:

```
0 => array [
    0 => "A"
    1 => "B"
    2 => "C"
  ]
1 => array [
    "order" => array [
      0 => "B"
      1 => "C"
      2 => "E"
    ]
  ]
2 => "B"
```

While displaying data I have done:

```
@foreach($data as $key => $list)       
<li style="display:block"><span>{{$key}}</span>. 
    <span>{{ is_array($list) ? implode (", ", $list) : $list }}</span>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Since there is different array coming, it says Array to string conversion when it comes to 1 index. How can I handle this?

Comment: I think because index 1 is multidimensional

Comment: @ket-c How can I solve that?

Comment: By doing another ternary to check for array in the **TRUE**

Comment: If I may ask, does all index 1 data have this structure?

Comment: I think you should have nested foreach instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorganize the data array elements in the same format:

```php
$data = [
   ["A", "B", "C"],
   ["B", "C", "E"],
   ["B"],
];
```

Controller

```php
$data = [
   ["A", "B", "C"],
   "order" =>  [
      ["B", "C", "E"]
   ],
   "B"
];
$items = [];
foreach ($data as $i => $datum) {    
    if (is_string($i)) { // handle $data[$i]["order"]  
       $items[] = current($datum);   
       continue;
    }

    $items[] = (array) $datum; // handle $data[2] (B)
}
```

Transfer items to the template and foreach it

```php
// this is an example, use template engine syntax
foreach($items as $listItems) {
   var_dump(implode(', ', $listItems));
}
```